# Display null value when total is 0

Tags: netsuite, case-statement, saved-searches

I have a NetSuite search which displays inventory values from multiple locations by custom field value. Formula I'm currently using is listed below and working just fine. I just need to modify this formula to display null value, when total comes to 0 based on the formula calculation.

MAX(case when {custitem37} = '4' and {inventorylocation.id} = '1' OR {custitem37} = '04' and {inventorylocation.id} = '1' then {locationquantityavailable} else 0 end) + MAX(case when {custitem37} = '4' and {inventorylocation.id} = '6' OR {custitem37} = '04' and {inventorylocation.id} = '6' then {locationquantityavailable} else 0 end)

Comment: Unfortunately far as I know you will have to wrap it in a CASE and repeat everything twice. `CASE WHEN (XXXXX) != 0 THEN (XXXXX) ELSE NULL END `

Comment: Can you not wrap your formula in NULLIF(<your formula>, 0)?

Comment: Yes, actually NULLIF worked for me....I had tried it right after I had posted the question. Example formula:  MAX(case when {custitem37} = 'OS' and {inventorylocation.id} = '1' then {locationquantityavailable} else 0 end) + NULLIF(MAX(case when {custitem37} = 'OS' and {inventorylocation.id} = '6' then {locationquantityavailable} else 0 end) ,0)

Answer (score 0):

Used the NULLIF: MAX(case when {custitem37} = 'OS' and {inventorylocation.id} = '1' then {locationquantityavailable} else 0 end) + NULLIF(MAX(case when {custitem37} = 'OS' and {inventorylocation.id} = '6' then {locationquantityavailable} else 0 end) ,0)